# runtime cucumber exception :Failed to create scenario runner

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, cucumber, data-driven-tests

This is my feature and this is the error log. pom.xml is at the bottom. I have two feature files. I want both of them to run when I run it. But I have a mistake but I cant figure out.
I search from google first but I cant find a solution.

```
Feature: ML Funnel Listing
  Scenario Outline: ML Funnel Proposal Listing
    Given I choose Mortgage Credit
    And I fill Credit Loan field as "<loan>"
    And I choose Expire field as "<expire>"
    And I press Calculate button
    Then I see credit proposal list
    Examples:
      | loan | expire |
      |100000|1 Year (12 Month)|
```

---

```
> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to create scenario runner
>   at
> cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.buildFeatureElementRunners(FeatureRunner.java:85)
>   at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.<init>(FeatureRunner.java:31)
>   at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.addChildren(Cucumber.java:106)   at
> cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:62)  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
>   at
> org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
>   at
> org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
>   at
> org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>   at
> org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>   at
> org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>   at
> org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
>   at
> com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
>   at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
>   at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
>   at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
> Caused by: org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError    at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:418)    at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)   at
> org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:112)    at
> cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.<init>(ExamplesRunner.java:21)
>   at
> cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.<init>(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:24)
>   at
> cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.buildFeatureElementRunners(FeatureRunner.java:81)
>   ... 17 more
```

Comment: Which version of Cucumber are you using? Make sure you have a recent version of Cucumber and IDEA.

Comment: cucumber-java and cucumber-core versions are 1.2.0.

Comment: That version of Cucumber works with JUnit 4.11 but not 4.12. Try upgrading Cucumber to 1.2.6.